# Pi terminal bootstrap program failed to run error

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I am trying to run a springboot and jar file one pi bootup but when i run the backend in terminal on the pi, i get the error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description: 
The Tomcat connector configured to listen to port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

my question is, is there a command i can run in the terminal before tunning the java backend to make the port available? Thanks!

Comment: What, like killing whatever process is already listening on that port?  That might cause problems for whoever is using that other process...

Comment: yea i know but i just want to kill the process already on the port.